# Remove apostrophe on python numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying yo solve a simple matrix problem on python 3 using numpy with this code:

```
import numpy

change_array = numpy.array(input().strip().split(' '))
change_array.shape = (3,3)

print(change_array)
```

The output of this program with input:
 `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` is

```
[['1' '2' '3']
 ['4' '5' '6']
 ['7' '8' '9']]
```

I want the output without apostrophes like this:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

But I haven't find the way yet, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You have to tell numpy to interpret the strings as integers. Insert `, dtype = int` at the end of numpy.array().

Comment: The apostrophies are quote marks, showing that the values are strings, not integers.  Look at `change.array.dtype`.

Comment: indeed supplying the additional parameter `dtype = int`: [`numpy.array(input().strip().split(' '), dtype = int)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array) should fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way or other you have to convert the strings to integers:

```
In [86]: x = np.array(input().strip().split())
1 2 3
In [87]: x
Out[87]: array(['1', '2', '3'], dtype='<U1')   # string dtype
In [88]: x.astype(int)
Out[88]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

or

```
In [89]: x = np.array(input().strip().split(), dtype=int)
4 5 6
In [90]: x
Out[90]: array([4, 5, 6])
```

or do the conversion at the list level

```
In [91]: x = [int(i) for i in input().strip().split()]
1 2 3
In [92]: x
Out[92]: [1, 2, 3]
In [93]: np.array(x)
Out[93]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

But watch out for bad values

```
In [94]: x = np.array(input().strip().split(), dtype=int)
1 2 a
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-20cd8929f6ac> in <module>()
----> 1 x = np.array(input().strip().split(), dtype=int)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `ast.literal_eval`. This would require inputting some extra characters. However, it is also more explicit since you are defining the shape in your input.

```
import numpy as np
from ast import literal_eval

change_array = np.array(literal_eval(input()))
# input: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

change_array
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [4, 5, 6],
#        [7, 8, 9]])
```